# Comments with timestamp and author?

Tags: comments, timestamp

When working in a large project with many authors it could be a nice feature if the IDE could record when and who is writing a ceratin comment. I would be enough if this information only was visible with a tooltip on the comment-text. Is there any add-on that could do this?

Im working with C# in VS2010.

Update:
A quick solution could of course be a macro that inserted my name and the current time a the current position.

Answer (score 0):

Have your source control system add these values each time the file is checked in.